# Android TTS TextToSpeech Best Practice

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am aware of the lifecycle of TTS, Activity and Application. However I have a hard time making sure to release TTS after using it, especialy if a user presses Home and so on. I want an App that speaks during multiple Activities. I don't know how long my App needs to talk and during talking I need to update a View from time to time. Perhaps someone could point out a good example for best practice in handling the creation and releasing of my TTS Object.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the Tts object? In an activity or service?

Comment: In order to keep things simple I create my tts in an activity. But I could change this. Would a service improve my stability issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the Tts object in onStart() and shutdown Tts in onStop(). This way when your app is not visible, the TTS resources are not being used.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I changed quite a few things in my App. My TTS is in a Service now. However the answer is right. Thank's

Comment: Hoan Nguyen can you tell me how can i display each speaking word in toast.